# SQL server Listener removal

Tags: availability-groups, listener

Hi I am planning to drop and recreate the listener with same name what is the best approach? Can i drop the listener from WFCS by removing the resorces or Drop the listener from SQL using SQL command? Please let me know which is the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

Use TSQL, SSMS, or Powershell, per:  [Remove an availability group listener (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/remove-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)